# Is there a definitive list for ALL of KITT's capabilities?

Tags: knight-rider

In a practical sense, we know many different cars were used to do different stunts and driving for specific scenes in *Knight Rider.* In-story, it is also explained that KITT had a lot of standard capabilities: his A.I., the turbo booster, enhanced communication and scanning capabilities, grappling hooks and molecular shell, amongst others, but that Bonnie or one of the other techs would on occasion outfit him for a particular mission with something unique (special ATV tires, or a specific laser emitter, for instance).

Are there any specs or a list available which states **all** of KITT's abilities, both standard and specialized?

Comment: Evil windshield wipers.

Comment: @CBredlowHa! Funny!

Comment: Don't forget the film "Knightrider 2000" where KITT's AI stuff gets placed into the prototype for the Knight 4000